# DataGrid Column Control

Tags: c#, datagrid

I want to check one column of datagrid to see if it is 0 or 1. I also want it to print the number of 0 or 1 and write it to the textbox.  I tried this code but it gives an error.

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns["values4"].ToString() = 0) 
{ 
    int sayi;
    sayi = (dataGridView1.Rows.Count);
    txtBasarili.Text = sayi;
}
```

Comment: use == "0"  maybe it will work

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns["values4"].ToString() == "0") 
            { 
                int sayi;
                sayi = (dataGridView1.Rows.Count);
                txtBasarili.Text = sayi;
            }
```